# Redirect to a action from another action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a ASP.net MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 . I  want to redirect to a index action which has a Boolean parameter.  calling method is below . Without changing the return type  how can i redirect to the index action.

Action which  needs to redirect to Index action

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Create(string name)
{

     return Json(result);
}




 public IActionResult Index(bool isUpdate)
 {

 }
```

Comment: You have to change the return type if you want to return a redirect response.

Comment: Is there any special reason that you created return type of Create as JsonResult? I mean you calling this action method from Jquery or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a redirect response from your `Create` action method without changing the current return type!

Change the return type to `ActionResult` and then you can use the `RedirectToAction` method to return a `RedirectResponse`.

`RedirectResult` and `JsonResult`, both inherits from `ActionResult` class

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string name)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { isUpdate = true });
}

public IActionResult Index(bool isUpdate)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to another action Method without changing the return type. 
In your scenario, you will have to change the return type to "ActionResult" and set your return type in fuction declaration to "IActionResult".